# Visual Studio 2008 Duplicate Project folders issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web, project

Every time I create a new website in Visual Studio 2008, two folders are created in the projects folder; ie website1 & website1 (2)(using defaults for example).  Folder "Website1" will have the web.config, the default.aspx and code behind page and the app_data folder.  "Website1 (2)" will have the *.suo and *.sln files in it.  Any ideas on why this is happening and more importantly how to correct?

Im not sure when this started but I have other website projects that are not this way.

I have searched for solutions here on Stackoverflow and with Google but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to find the cause but restoring the setting to the defaults has corrected the issue.

Menu: Tools > Import and Export Settings -- and choose reset settings.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting my settings to the defaults did not work for me.

What did work was instead of saving to the Projects folder:
C:\Users\baxter\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebSite1

I saved it to the WebSites folder:
C:\Users\baxter\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1

I now only get 1 folder created WebSite1 not WebSite1 and WebSite1(2)